# Multiple using declarations throw 'IOException' but statements don't when writing files

Tags: c#, using-statement

`using` declarations were just introduced in `C# 8.0` but they don't behave the same as `using` blocks, or so i think.

The following nested `using` block works fine:

```
using (var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(serviceKey))
using (var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    resource?.CopyTo(file);
}
```

But when i convert to a `using` declaration as follows, i get an `IOException` which says the file is being used by another process:

```
using var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(serviceKey);
using var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
resource?.CopyTo(file);
```

I want to understand what's different and how\when to use the new `using` declaration?

Comment: Use it any time you are working with an object that implements `IDisposable` and you do not plan on disposing it yourself.

Comment: Is it possible that the file pointed to by `path` is actually open in another process? Word and Excel are very good at setting exclusive locks on files. It could even be your own process if you are calling both statement blocks within Tasks or async.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning That's not the case, the first `using` statement runs ok. It only throws and exception when i use a declaration instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both using declaration differ in the way they resolve scope.
Old Using used to define its own scope using the curly braces,

```
using var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(serviceKey);
using (var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    resource?.CopyTo(file);
}
```

Here both resource and file will be disposed the moment the closing braces are found.

With, The new declaration if you haven,t defined a scope like the above, It will automatically attach to the nearest scope,

```
void certainMethod()
{
   using var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(serviceKey);
   using var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
   resource?.CopyTo(file);
}
```

Here when the method call to `certainMethod` ends, Dispose for resource and file will be called.

Edit: To your case,
There shouln't be any issue if your code is doing just this, But if there are two of such blocks, First one will work but second will fail,
Example,

```
 void certainMethod()
    {
       using var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(serviceKey);
       using var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
       resource?.CopyTo(file);
       using var oneMoreFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
       //This will fail
       resource?.CopyTo(oneMoreFile );

    }
```

Comment: So, basically, `using` declarations starts disposing at the end of the nearest block if i don't explicitly wrap them in one?

Comment: yes that's correct, It can be even an if block or a loop block.

Comment: Added an example of failure.